# Creating a Gradient Heatmap with Third Variable as a Fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a gradient heatmap instead of a geom_point() of x and y, filled by z.

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 63 | 71 | 1 |
| 59 | 67.5 | 0.5 |
| 55 | 73.5 | 0.33 |
| 60 | 61 | 0.09 |

I have tried geom_raster() but that is not as aesthetically pleasing since it is just geom_tile() but blurry. I also tried stat_density_2d but that obviously ignores z in favor of doing densities.

Hope this makes sense? It's a little tricky and I feel like a "hacky" solution is best.

The ideal output would look something similar to this but again, instead of the gradient being based on the density, I would like it to be based on y (a bunch of rates from 0 to 1).
[image]

Comment: `df %>% tidyr::uncount(z*100) %>% ggplot(aes(x,y)) + stat_density_2d()`?

Comment: @JonSpring Tried this and got hit with "Can't convert from weights: due to loss of precision"

Comment: Maybe this: `df1 %>% uncount(as.integer(z*100)) %>% ggplot(aes(x, y)) + geom_density2d_filled()`

Comment: @JonSpring that did work but just to confirm, I'm trying to get the gradient to be z instead of counts/densities, and the legend for geom_density2d_filled() is giving me "level", is that still just the denisty but instead x and y are grouped by z with uncount?

Comment: You could use `geom_density2d_filled(contour_var = "ndensity")` to scale against the maximum density.